# Magento2-Refused to load image

Tags: magento2

Refused to load the image 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1376484/stacy.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Comment: what you want to explain more

Comment: When I am loading the image. the above error is occuring. It occuring with both http and https.

Comment: this link --- http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1376484/stacy.jpg' my browser working perfect  and not show any error

Comment: I am trying to load this jpg with texture loader(Three.js) in magento. My code is:---                           let stacy_txt = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1376484/stacy.jpg');